Contentful CMS - extract image url for BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET
I use Contentful and have issue doing custom formatting when my RichText receives the content.json for rendering.
In the case of [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET] nodes I try to "process" them in Options but the url itself of the asset is not in that node unfortunately. I found the way to find the url is to look on content.links (no content.json) but that doesn't seem to be accessible from OPTIONS
  [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: (node) => {
  console.log("Apply Options asset-hyperlink");
  return (
    <img
      src={node.links?}
      height='600'
      width='400'
      className='h-20 w-20'
    />
  )
}

Some older code with Contentful CMS used:
return (
    <ContentfulImage
      src={node.data.target.fields.file.url}
      height={node.data.target.fields.file.details.image.height}
      width={node.data.target.fields.file.details.image.width}
      alt={node.data.target.fields.title}
      className='h-20 w-20'
    />
  )

but node.data.target.fields does not exist anymore
